# Extract string before colon or parenthesis with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the string `muscle pain` from the following strings.
I need to use a regular expression that works for all three cases.

```
string1 = 'A1 muscle pain: immunotherapy'
string2 = 'A2B_45 muscle pain: topical medicine e.g. ....'
string3 = 'A2_45 muscle pain (pain): topical medicine e.g. ....'
```

The following code works for `string1` and `string2`. But it does not work for `string3`. What I get is always `muscle pain (pain)`. Can anyone help me with that. I tried so many times with different expression but could not figure out how.

```
re.match(r"^[A-Z]+\d*[A-Z]*_?\d*\s(.*)[:\(]", string3).group(1)
```

Comment: Replace `(.*)[:\(]` with `([^:(]*)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^[\dA-Z_]+ ([^\(:]+)`.

It starts with `[\dA-Z_]+` at the beggining (note anchor `^`), followed by space.
Now, start capturing group until one of unwanted characters is met: `[^\(:]`.
You can add there more "unwanted" characters to alter regex to match differently.

First capturing group is what you want.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSW4qE/3)

You could try this pattern to remove space after third match: `^[\dA-Z_]+ ([\w ]+)(?=(:| \())`. [See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cSW4qE/4)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness First, it's up to OP what answer he considers as helping. Secondly, thanks for pointing things out, I corrected it, so 1st capturing group is the match OP wants.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I understand you :) added another pattern to make sure my answer deserved acceptance ;)

Comment: Yeah :) But now you don't need the second capturing group. I understand you were trying to make the lookahead different than mine, but...

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten the expression to:

```
^A\S+\s([^:(]*)(?=:|\s\()
```

- `^A` Assert position beginning of string.
- `\S+` Any non whitespace characters.
- `\s` Whitespace character.
- `([^:(]*)` Capture group. Match and capture anything other than a `(` bracket or `]` bracket.
- `(?=:|\s\()` Positive lookahead for `:` or whitespace followed by `(`.

Try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/QrD63T/1).

---

Python snippet:

```
import re
string1 = 'A1 muscle pain: immunotherapy'
string2 = 'A2B_45 muscle pain: topical medicine e.g. ....'
string3 = 'A2_45 muscle pain (pain): topical medicine e.g. ....'

print(re.match(r'^A\S+\s([^:(]*)(?=:|\s\()',string3).group(1))
```

Comment: thanks. Could you explain why my code does not work? I guess it's the last part of my expression.  But I do not know why.

Comment: Sure. As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/QrD63T/2), the pattern `(.*)` in `(.*)[:\(]` is matching anything greedily, therefore it will match as much as possible up to either a  `(` or `:`. For the third string, it will match up to the `:` following `(pain)` because of the greedyness. You could improve it by using `(.*?)`, therefore making the pattern lazy, however as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/QrD63T/3) the match will include unwanted whitespace, `:` and `(` in your result (that is why I included the lookahead in my answer).

Comment: I  got it. Thanks a lot. @UnbearableLightness

Comment: I probably pressed the wrong button. Just upvoted. thanks.@UnbearableLightness